Why GDB pretty printer can't work for binary compiled by clang++?
GDB version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
clang++ version: clang version 10.0.0
test code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::vector<int64_t> vec{1,2,3};
   return 0;
}

I use clang++ to compile it: clang++ -std=c++11 -g -o test test.cpp
then use gdb to debug test program: gdb test
when I print vec, the output is:
(gdb) p vec
$1 = {<> = {_M_impl = {<allocator<long>> = {<new_allocator<long>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x206010, _M_finish = 0x206028, 
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x206028}}, <No data fields>}

if I change to use g++ to compile, the GDB output is:
(gdb) p vec
$1 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 3 = {1, 2, 3}

Does someone know how to let GDB pretty printer work for clang++ ? Thanks.

libc++ had pretty printers for gdb (see here). Does this file exist on your side?

Thanks, for my example, I use clang++ to compile, but the c++ std library is still libstdc++, not libc++, so libc++ pretty printers can't work for libstdc++.

I didn't even know you could use libstdc++ when compiling with clang, so that's very important information. But it looks like clang writes different debug info than g++ (try p/r vec on the g++ executable to see the difference), and that's probably the reason why the pretty printer doesn't work.
